# Image in Email Signature on iPhone

Tags: ios, css, iphone, email, html-email

I am creating an code for an email signature. The image is never left align on the email client on my iPhone and I have no idea why.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" style="padding:0;margin:0;height:45px;width:230px;">
                                <ul style="padding:0;margin:0;height:45px;width:230px;">
                                    <li style="text-align:left;margin:0;padding:0;height:45px;width:230px;">
                                        <a target='_blank' href="https://www.mypage.com" style="margin:0;padding:0;width:230px;height:45px;">
                                            <img style="padding:0;margin:0;" height="45px" width="230px" src="https://www.mypage.com/logo.gif" alt="Logo mypage" />
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </td> ......
```

The problem is visualized on the image below:
[image]

Is there something I can do?

Thanks for helping me.

Best regards,
Yab86

Answer (score 1):

If the linked `<img>` is the only thing in that `<td>`, can you remove the `<ul>`? Or is there another reason the list is there?

Email clients do weird things to margin and padding of block level elements like `<ul>` and`<li>`, sometimes even if they're reset with inline CSS. If you don't need a list here, why introduce the complexity?

```
<table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td height="45" width="230" align="left" style="padding:0;">
            <a target='_blank' href="https://www.mypage.com">
                <img align="left" style="display: block; margin:0;" height="45" width="230" src="https://www.mypage.com/logo.gif" alt="Logo mypage" />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```